# How do I disable a button when the value in the NumericUpDown control is greater than a certain number?

Tags: c#, button, numericupdown

The button only disables after I click on it. I want it to disable without any interaction as soon as the value in the NumericUpDown control is incremented above a specific point. I have goggled but found no answers, here is my code:

```
    private void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (numericud.Value > myArray[r, c] || myArray[r, c] == 0)
            DisableButton(mybtn);            
        myArray[r, c] = CalcNewMax(myArray[r, c]);
        OpenNewForm();
    }

    private void DisableButton(Button selectedbtn)
    {
        selectedbtn.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your code should already work, assuming that `mybtn.Enabled = false;` is executing.  It would be clearer if you surrounded that line of code with braces.

Comment: Small, Complete, Example please

Comment: dont get discouraged by negative votes. could u elaborate on the code part??

Comment: I voted to re-open because it appears as though the author has an actual problem, and could make an answerable question if he edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling the method "mybtn_Click()" when the button gets clicked, not when the value of the numeric up-down changes. In the "Events" part of the properties of the button check out if the "MouseClick" event is set to call "mybtn_Click()".

Afterwards go to the "Events" part of the properties of the numeric up-down and set the "ValueChanged" event to call "mybtn_Click()". I also advise you to change the name of the method to a more suitable one before that.

And lastly, you don't need to make a whole new method for simply changing the Enabled value of the button: simply replace the line

`DisableButton(mybtn);`

with

```
mybtn.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I just noticed that myself from looking at the previous example but thanks for replying at least now i know what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code that works for a specific example.

I don't see any specific problems with your code, so if I were you, I'd put some breakpoints in to make sure that your condition is fulfilled, and that everything is proceeding as you think it is.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numericUpDown1.Value > 5)
                button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As an additional note, Visual Studio will automatically generate the `numericUpDown1_ValueChanged` handler when you double-click on the UpDown control in the designer

Comment: Lol, found the answer and went to respond but got network error and yours was already here.. i agree with this one :)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm still pretty new to programming and it was a rather naive mistake for me to make. The code was just being handled by the wrong event; it was being executed after the actual button Click and not the ValueChanged.